# Confusion in counting outcomes.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have this problem,

> You have to select two numbers from the first 20 natural numbers. What is the probability that the sum of the two numbers will be odd?

We know,

1. There are 10 even and 10 odd numbers between 1 and 20.
2. The sum of two numbers will be odd only when one number is even and another is odd.

Solution given in the book,

There are $ 10 \choose 1 $ ways for choosing an odd and same number of ways for choosing andeven number between 1 and 20. And there are total $ 20 \choose 2 $ ways of choosing two numbers. Hence, probability that sum is odd will be
$$ \frac{{10 \choose 1}{10 \choose 1}}{20 \choose 2} $$
But shouldn't there be a factor of 2 in the denominator as a pair of two numbers can be chosen in two different ways, first you select x then y or you select y then x? Why shouldn't we count this as 2 different outcomes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there shouldn't be an additional factor of $2$ in the denominator.  The denominator and numerator must each be enumerated in a consistent manner.  In the numerator, the enumeration **ignores** whether the first number chosen is odd or even.  That is, in the numerator, the enumeration represents how many combinations of $(1)$ odd, $(1)$ even number there are, without any regard to the order that the numbers are chosen.

That is why, for consistency, it is appropriate that the denominator also focus only on the number of combinations of $20$ numbers, taken $2$ at a time.

Comment: Oh you mean there is a factor of 2 in numerator and denominator both which cancel each other?

Comment: @1147 No, I mean that when you attack problems like this, you have two alternatives, when computing the probability equal $$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}}$$.  You can either compute both $N$ and $D$ as combinations, where order is irrelevant, or you can compute $N$ and $D$ as permutations, where order is relevant.  The source that you cited chose the first method.  Either method is valid.  There is no *cancelling* the factor of $2$, because both the numerator and denominator are construing order as irrelevant.

Comment: But aren't (13, 7) and (7, 13) two different outcomes?

Comment: @1147 No, under the (valid) presumption that the numerator and denominator will both ignore the order that the numbers are chosen, $(13,7)$ and $(7,13)$ both refer to the same combination, namely $\{13,7\}$.  Note that the diffence between a combination and a permutation is that with a combination, the order is irrelevant.  It is valid (and sometimes easier, as in this problem) to consistently enumerate both the numerator and denominator as combinations, rather than permutations.

Answer (score 0):

The given solution is correct, assuming that you cannot choose the same number twice.

To understand the solution (they used the hypergeometric) you can calculate the solution manually...

$$\mathbb{P}[\text{Odd},\text{Even}]+\mathbb{P}[\text{Even},\text{Odd}]=\frac{10}{20}\times\frac{10}{19}+\frac{10}{20}\times\frac{10}{19}=\frac{\binom{10}{1}\binom{10}{1}}{\binom{20}{2}}$$

Comment: Can you please explain the last step?

Comment: @1147:  simply verify, expanding RHS, that the two solutions are equivalent